# How to break wall of text into paragraphs in google docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, line-breaks, paragraph

I have a google document that is formatted with soft enters or line feed (\r) chars, often several consecutive ones. I want to replace those with paragraph breaks.

Since the Find/Replace function apparently can not insert special chars I use google app script. But even that seems to have some limitations. So it can not match \r or \n, but \v instead.

I use the google docs add-on "Show" to show the special chars in my document.

Sadly I didn't manage to figure out the char that marks a paragraph break.

According to the add-on "Show", this code inserts soft enters instead of paragraph breaks:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
body.replaceText("\\v+", "\n");
```

So is there a proper paragraph break char(s) that I can use, at all?

Do I need to use insertParagraph(), otherwise? Can i use "\r\r"s as paragraph delimiters?

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/R6KdaD9vLnY). Try using `char(10)` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @abielita  you mean like `body.replaceText("\\v+", char(10));` ? That gives me "ReferenceError: char not defined". This works, but gives me the same result as "\n" - it inserts line feed (\r) chars: `body.replaceText("\\v+", String.fromCharCode(10));` Please do elaborate what you mean.